# How to give support of third party library like pyzbar in pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to convert .py project to .exe but pyzbar library is not supporting the pyinstaller.So how to give third party library support in pyinstaller.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supporting"???

Comment: After converting whole .py to .exe,it is giving error of pyzbar library.

Comment: So add a minimal version of your code and full error trace to the question.